# Заставить javascript интерпретатор выдавать ошибку если в addEventListener неверное имя события

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, addeventlistener

Есть возможность в javascript интерпретаторе выдавать ошибку если в addEventListener неверное имя события?

Например пишем:

```
document.addEventListener('onkeydown', function (e) {…});
```

При выполнении данной строки ничего не происходит.
Ни ошибки, ни присвоения обработчика событий.

Это понятно что в данном конкретном случае место 'onkeydown' надо писать 'keydown'.
Но в других случаях ты можешь этого не заметить.
А javascript run-time молчит, как будто все нормально.
Тестировал в хроме.
Может есть какие-то специальные javascript машины, которые более строго подходят к данным ошибкам?

Comment: нет нельзя, так как можно делать пользовательские события, которые могут быть любыми. Можно попробовать воспользоваться `typescript`, в котором прописаны типы для стандартных событий.

Comment: В описании addEventListener допускается возможность указывать имя события любым. Да, есть предопределенные имена, однако, это не является ошибкой и ни одна среда разработки не может угадать, вы ошиблись или так и задумали.

Comment: самое простое решение которое приходит в голову - перехватить или проксировать addEvent. `let proxyAddEvent = function(abc){if(ValidEventNames.includes(abc)){document.addEventListener(abc);}else{console.log("засунь этот свой " + abc + " знаешь куда?")}}` это конечно не готовый код, а скорее намёк, если вдруг кто не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна такая проверка на стандартные обработчики событий и вы знаете какие обработчики вам нужны в проекте, напишите функцию которая принимает событие в аргументе и возвращает его если с проверкой всё ОК., иначе выбрасывайте ошибку. Вызывайте эту функцию в обработчиках.

Answer (score 0):

Метод addEventListener первым параметром принимает значение - строка. **Любая строка**. Есть предопределенные типы событий в типе DocumentEventMap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, у нас есть Бяка, которая хочет послать сообщение для Буки, и сообщение это не должно зависеть от действий пользователя на странице

Вот наша Бяка

```
<div id="byaka">Жду буку</div>
```

А вот так мы можем передать сообщение Буке из любого места и по любому событию

```
  document.addEventListener('buka', function (e) { //Вешаем слушателя
    console.log('buka получил сообщение');
  });
  let event = new Event('buka', {bubbles: true}); // Генерим событие

  const byaka = document.getElementById('byaka'); // Берем элемент
  byaka.dispatchEvent(event); // Кричим во весь document что сработало событие. Все кто подписан на событие 'buka' получат его
```

Таким образом, мы можем создавать свои события и подписывать на них любые элементы.

И так же отвечая на вопрос - как защитится от опечатки в имени события: Быть внимательным )
Не уверен, что даже TypeScript спасет, с учетом того, в addEventListener может быть передана любая произвольная строка